# How do I work out this complicated MYSQL query inside two while loops?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a music player, where a song can be added to a playlist. However, if the song has *already* been added to the playlist, I want to hide *that* playlist for that *particular* song. I say *that* because you can have more than one playlist and one song can be in multiple playlists.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

      $shuffle = $_GET["shuffle"];

        $songsContent = $db->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_band='$band' && album_name='$album'");

      $numSongsContent = $songsContent->num_rows;

      $number = 0;

      while($fetch_songs = mysqli_fetch_array($songsContent)) {
        $number++;
        $song_path = $fetch_songs["song_path"];
        $song_title = $fetch_songs["song_title"];
        $song_band = $fetch_songs["song_band"];
        echo "<div class='songs' path='Music/$song_band/$song_path.mp3' number='$number' total='$numSongsContent'> $song_title <div id='song_playlist'> <i class='fa fa-plus' aria-hidden='true'></i>
 Add to Playlist <div id='song_playlist_popup'>";


 $getPlaylists = $db->query("SELECT * FROM playlists");


 while($fetch_playlists = mysqli_fetch_array($getPlaylists)) {
    $playlist_name = $fetch_playlists["playlist_name"];
```

This is the part of the code that I'm having difficulty with. In this part, this is where the playlists are outputted. I'm trying to control this output by a conditional statement. But, the data seems to completely ignore the condition:

```
 $checkDuplicates = $db->query("SELECT * FROM playlist_songs WHERE playlist_name='$playlist_name' AND song_name='$song_title'");
    $numDuplicates = $checkDuplicates->num_rows;

    if($numDuplicates == 0) {
      echo "<div id='playlist_name'> <span song='$song_title'> $playlist_name </span> </div>";
    }

 }

 echo  "<div id='playlist_name2'> <span id='playlist_input_errors'></span> <input id='playlist_input' placeholder='Create new Playlist' song='$song_title'> </div> </div> </div> </div>";

      }

      ?>
```

How do I fix this query to only allow playlists that haven't been added to a song? Thanks...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I'll fix it later. Any help would greatly be appreciated...

Comment: There is nothing "complicated" about this query. What you did what to turn PHP into a db engine by not performing a single query with a join.

Comment: @Drew This is my first year of programming. Would you mind giving an example... :)